SharePoint columns size limit
I hope you’re all doing well.
I’m facing a BIG issue:
For the past four months, I’ve been working on a flow connected to a SharePoint list. Today, when I tried to add more columns to my list, I encountered this error:

I attempted to uncheck most of the columns from the main view, but the problem persists.
I cannot delete any columns, and I need to add more to complete my project.
Can anyone help me overcome this limit?
Thank you in advance.

Each  SharePoint list item can max. occupy 8,000 bytes per row and 300 Bytes are reserved, so you can use 7,700 bytes
You can get all columns from your list if you use the SharePoint REST api in your browser. Simply open
<Yoursiteurl>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<your list name>')/fields

and save the XML. You can transfrom that result into an Excel file using Power Query.
Now you can count the fields and determine their type (i.e. using the field "TypeAsString" Property).
For the size of each field type refer to this table
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/software-boundaries-and-limits#Column
Sum that up to calculate your list size.
Reference:
Microsoft Sharepoint Online - total size of the columns in this list exceeds the limit

Hi Amy, Thank you very much for your prompt reply.
I followed your instructions, but the question now is how to bypass this issue.
Thank you in advance :)
